# VOIP in C#, asp.net or Java

Tags: c#, java, asp.net, voip

Could you people please give some good resource / ideas of implementing VOIP in c#.net, Asp.net or Java.

Why I am specifying 2 different language platforms is we are yet to take up a call.

Basically we don't have the idea henceforth the concept is more important to us.

We are going to make a White board application and one of the client requirement is

> White board should have VOIP
>   conferencing, chat image sharing and
>   ability to upload .pdf files

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I reckon your looking into developing software like [orange business webex](https://orangebusinesscomp.webex.com/mw0305l/mywebex/default.do?siteurl=orangebusinesscomp&service=1) or something similar. The software is not too difficult to develop. First, are you planning to write the entire application yourself or just purchase the components and integrate ? I would recommend you shop around for components and just integrate because VOIP is rather complex.

Here is a link for [SIP communicator](http://sip-communicator.org/) in java which supports VOIP

Answer (score 2):

Doing simple point-to-point VOIP isn't too difficult.  Basically, you need a codec on each end, and then typically use UDP to send encoded packets from one end to the other.

There can also be network connectivity issues, particularly related to NAT.

If you want to interoperate with existing VOIP-based systems, then you will need to support one of the underlying connection protocols, such as H.323, and you may also need monitoring and control over RTP.  Those protocols are notoriously complex.

There are a bunch of tricks to play when doing this kind of thing with a managed language like C# or Java, particularly related to avoiding hiccups due to GC.

Answer (score 1):

A link to a few more Java VOIP projects/components:
http://voip.dev.java.net/

One "gotcha" to beware of, in terms of future functionality, is that Java's (as opposed to JavaFX's) video support is something of an open question at the moment.